# How to reassign an object so that it changes the referenced object as well?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an array of objects:

```
var people = [
  {name: "Jack", height: 180},
  {name: "Marry", height: 170},
  {name: "Susan", height: 162},
]
```

If I take the first person and change the height like this:

```
var jack = people[0];     
jack.height = 163;
```

Then this change is reflected in the object in the array as well like this:

```
people = [
      {name: "Jack", height: 163},
      {name: "Marry", height: 170},
      {name: "Susan", height: 162},
    ]
```

However if I reassign the object like this

```
 jack = {name: "Jack the developer", height: 163}
```

The array doesn't change:

```
people = [
      {name: "Jack", height: 163},
      {name: "Marry", height: 170},
      {name: "Susan", height: 162},
    ]
```

How should I assign `jack` so that it changes the reference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: You changed the nature of the question quite a bit with your edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your way you can do using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

**DEMO**

```js
const arr=[
      {name: "Jack", height: 163},
      {name: "Marry", height: 170},
      {name: "Susan", height: 162},
    ] ,
    jack = {name: "Jack the developer", height: 163};
    
Object.assign(arr[0],jack);

console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```

---

You can also use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method of array and merge new value using [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

**DEMO**

```js
const arr=[
      {name: "Jack", height: 163},
      {name: "Marry", height: 170},
      {name: "Susan", height: 162},
    ] ,
    jack = {name: "Jack the developer", height: 163};
    
let result = arr.find(({name})=>name=="Jack");

if(result){
Object.assign(result,jack);
};

console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```

Comment: Thanks, `Object.assign(newjack,jack)` was what I wanted.

Comment: BTW, the `find` is not necessary, neither is the `let` and `const` even a `var` would be fine. `Object.assign` would do the trick.

Comment: As you are using `people[0]` so you can easily do using Object.assign(). See updated answer.

Comment: @shampoo: Be aware that this won't handle cases where you want properties removed. This isn't a magic method that gives you the functionality you were looking for. It's just a convenience for assigning properties of one object to another.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
jack = {name: "Jack the developer", height: 163};
```

You're creating a new object and assigning it to `jack`, instead of changing the current object, E.g.:

```
jack.name = "John";
```

Answer (score 1):

JS does have reference types, which is why this code works:

```
var jack = people[0];    
jack.height = 163;
```

However, it still does assignments "by value" instead of "by reference", which means that `jack` holds the *value* of the reference type (the object) but if you *reassign* to `jack`, you're just reassigning *a new reference value* to a new object.

If JS had assignment "by reference", then your code would work, because `jack` would be referencing the original location of the object in the array, allowing you to work with `jack` as though you were working with that array index. That's not the case in JS.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do the assignment by reference?

Comment: No, all assignment is "by value". Closest you could get would be to nest each `people` object in another object, and assign that reference type to a variable. But that doesn't seem like a good solution. What's the actual problem at hand?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript `objects` are passed and assigned by **reference** so

```
var jack = people[0];
```

here `jack` and `people` are both references to the same object.

**So in first case**,

When you modify the value like this `jack.height = 163` then `people` object also get the reflected value.

**in your second case**,

With this line `jack = {name: "Jack the developer", height: 163};`
you're creating **totally** a new object `jack` with **new** value which will not reflect the `people` object that's why here you're not getting the re-assigned value.